# Converting long code file to separate files

Tags: r

I have two quite long R files with many function definitions and some comments irregularly between them. Is there any R function to move each function definition to a separate R file? It would be quite nice to name the new file with function name :).

Answer (score 3):

Content of the file (let's call it `tuttifrutti.R`) with all the functions could be something like this:

```
fun1 <- function(x) {
  # comment
  x * x
}

fun2 <- function(x) {
  # comment
  x/2
}
```

And then you can collect all functions and print them to samename file.

```
localenv <- new.env()

source("tuttifrutti.R", local = localenv)
sapply(localenv, print)

sapply(names(localenv), FUN = function(x, en) {
  dump(x, file = sprintf("%s.R", x), envir = en)
}, en = localenv)
```